# Wix Custom Action get current running msi file name

Tags: vbscript, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm trying to create this installer with Wix. Before or after InstallFinalize, I need to get the msi file name and then write that file name to config file inside the installation directory. Is this something possible?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows Installer property [OriginalDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has the path and name of the MSI database.  You'll have to parse out the name from the path.  WiX's util extension then has custom actions for [configuring](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlconfig.htm) XML files.

Comment: I see. But how would you use this property like for example in vbs?

Comment: Your question didn't mention VBScript.  If it had, I would have warned you that you shouldn't be using them in the first place. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can access a property in VBS like this:

```
Dim propValue = Session.Property("OriginalDatabase")
```

Also, very important, make sure the custom action is immediate. You cannot execute the above from a deferred custom action.

However, I recommend [Win32 DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1747/MSI-Custom-Action-DLL) for a custom action. In it you can use [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read the property value.

Comment: Thank you very much man! I now got it. I'm such a noob when it comes to vbs and didn't even know how to use Windows global variables.